# Torah Study and Tzitzit

Tags: torah-study, reward-punishment, tzitzis

The Sages have said "The study of Torah is equivalent to all of them [613 Mitzvot]." (*Kedushin 39b*)

I assume that means the reward of Torah study is equal to the reward of doing each individual mitzvah.

It is stated in regards to Tzitzit in *Sefer Bamidbar 15:39*

> This shall be fringes for you, and when you see it, you will remember all the commandments of the Lord **to perform them**, and you shall not wander after your hearts and after your eyes after which you are going astray.

So it seems that reward for Torah study apparently includes the reward for wearing tzitzit.

But if wearing tzitzit accumulates reward every second, and let’s say that gazing upon tzitzit will cause one to study Torah, **shouldn’t this make the merit/reward of tzitzit greater as it leads one to fulfill all commandments (and refrain from transgressing)?**

Comment: I don't think this is the deeper reasoning behind the mitzvah of tzitzis. Rashi says: The ציצית will remind one of all the commandments because the numerical value of the letters of the word ציצית is six hundred, and there are eight threads and five knots in the fringes, so that you have six hundred and thirteen, which is also the number of the commandments of the Torah. - There are different meforshim that explain that by looking at the tzitzis, we are reminded of the mitzvos. So it is not so that by studying Torah, we accomplish the mitzvah of wearing the tzitzis.

Comment: The mitzvah of Torah study is equal to the other mitzvos. It doesn't mean the reward is made up of all the other mitzvos. It just means equal.

Comment: Learning torah is equal [because](https://www.sefaria.org/Ikar_Tosafot_Yom_Tov_on_Mishnah_Peah.1.1.8) it brings you to do the mizvot. So torah and zizit are one and the same. Not two separate things

Answer (score 2):

Rav Shelomo Wolbe zt"l has a sefer called HaMitzvos haShqulus (The Mitzvos that are Equal" [in value to all the rest]. In it he looks at the 7 mitzvos that are described as "keneged kulam -- equal to them all" and some such, and finds that each epitomizes one of the Torah's primary values.

On pages 3-5, he lists them:

**1- Denying avodah zarah** (idolatry and other alien worship): "Whomever denies avodah zarah ascents to the entire Torah. (Sifrei, Shelach)

This mitzvah teaches the importance of setting values.

**2- Tzitzis**: "Tzitzis is equal to all the mitzvos." (Rashi, Shelach; R Wolbe knew Rashi was quoting a Chazal, I don't know where)

Tzitzis is typical of the mitzvos that exist to remind us of fundamental truths.

**3- Shabbos**: Why is the portion [in the Torah] of the wood cutter [who cut wood on Shabbos] adjacent to a portion about avodah zarah? TO tell you that someone who [routinely] desocrates the Shabbos [in public] is like an idolater. Because it too is equal to all the mitzvos." (Ibid.)

The sanctity of time. (See #7, Settling Israel)

**4- Torah study**: "Even all the mitzvos of the Torah are not equal to one concept from the Torah. (Yerushalmi Pei'ah 1:1)

The importance of wisdom.

**5- Beris Milah**: "Great is Milah because it is equal to all the mitzvos of the Torah." (Nedarim 32a)

Teaching the importance of mastery and sanctity of the body.

**6- Tzedaqah**: "And Rav Asi said, 'Tzedaqah is equal to all the mitzvos of the Torah." (Bava Basra 9a)

Demonstrates the importance of the power of giving to living according to the Torah.

**7- Settling the Land of Israel**: "There was an event involving Rabbi Yehudah ben Beseira, Rabbi Masia ben Chereish, Rabbi Chanina ben Achi, Rabbi Yehoshua and Rabbi Yonasan than they were leaving the Land. They reach Platos, and remembered the Land of Israel. They raised their eyes, shed tears, tore their clothes [in morning], and read the scripture, '...and you will inherit it and dwell and it, and be observant to do...' They said, 'Living in the Land of Israel is equal to all the mitzvos in the Torah.'" (Sifrei on Devarim 12:99, Yalqut Shim'oni)

The sanctity of space. (See also #2, Shabbos. Time and space are a pair.)

Rav Wolbe teaches that the seven combine to give us a complete outline of the Torah's form:

- Learn wisdom,
- commit to its values,
- internalize that wisdom and keep it alive in your mind through a discipline of rituals, and
- make your body,
- space and
- time holy by
- consecrating them all to giving to the other.